# Stuck with UI issues in making my app compatiable with ios6 and ios7

Tags: ios, ios6.0

[image]

I was developing an app for iOS 7 only. Just few hours back I was told iOS 6 compatiablity is required too. SO I started. As you can see that I have set the UI for iOS 6, in my XIBs.
But I didn't achieve the desired result. And the same problem is happening on iOS 7.

ALl this problem started , when I tried to make my app ios6 Compatiable. 
Please help.

Following are the option I have selected in the IB.[image]

Please forgive If am asking some Stupid Queswtion

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the problem is here? What is the desired result?

Comment: @Sammio2 as you can see on the Simulator, the left one. Its not showing the table completely. Moreover Its showing fine on Simulator. what should I do? please help

Comment: It looks like your storyboard xibs are not taking into account space at the top or the bottom of the view for the nav bar, status bar, or tab bar. Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @Sammio2 Am neither using the storyboard nor autolayouts. Any suggestion?

Comment: At the risk of sounding blunt, use autolayout... It's designed to help circumvent exactly these issues!

Comment: I got it. Had to fix delta issue for few components. Solved